# "Get your diaper changed" versus "change your diaper"

Tags: difference, phrase-request

In child language, would you ask your little one to go to their Mum to get their diaper changed as follows

> Come on go to your mum and **get** your diaper **changed**

I know saying

> Come on **change** your diaper

can't be said to a toddler since they can't do this task on their own

Comment: Your sentence is idiomatic, although it is our custom to end a sentence with a full stop. What is "child language"? In BrE, it might be "nappie" for diaper. (By the way, why would one not simply change the diaper rather than ordering the toddler to go find Mum?)

Comment: When you say "child language", you might be referring to what we usually call [baby talk](http://www.webmd.com/parenting/baby/infant-development-9/baby-talk).

Answer (score 1):

> Come on, go to your mum and get / have your diaper changed!

This is the (only) correct way of saying this. Why?

The sentence "Come on, *(you)* change your diaper", even though *you* is omitted, implies that the child should change its diaper, which of course, isn't the command you're looking for.
What you really mean is that the child should have its diaper changed by its mother. Therefore, you want to use **the second sentence,** as shown above.

Answer (score -1):

I think the correct sentence would be
"Go to your mom and ask her to change your diaper"
as the mum is not a service facility for changing diapers.

But you would go to the phone company shop to get your phone fixed.